# Text, audio resources in windows store apps

Tags: c#, text, resources, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have several older projects, that uses .resx files to keep resources. I have to develop a WinStore app and i don't find any methods to store and reach from code for example a .txt file (and for sounds .wav-s, etc.). How can be done this?
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx) has a number of examples but the basics are that you create a Uri for an ms-appx:/// URL that references the file and then use the StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync() to get the file:

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/logo.png");
var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```